# How can I convert source code using lambda?

Tags: java, android, lambda, rx-java

I implemented the below code.

It was okay at first, but as time went by and other code was added, it became messy.

So I decided to use lambda.

But I don't know how to convert it using lambda.
I tried many ways but it didn't work.

How can I convert it? And
If there is a place to see the related materials below, please suggest me. Thank you!

**Below is my code**

```
public void SaveBeaconId(){
    myCompositeDisposable.add(BeaconService.getBeaconObservable()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ProximityZoneContext[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(ProximityZoneContext[] proximityZoneContexts) {
                    for(int i=0; i<proximityZoneContexts.length; i++) {
                        bId = proximityZoneContexts[i].getDeviceId();
                        if (!beaconList.contains(bId)) {
                            beaconList.add(bId);
                            Log.d("OnNext Beacon add: ", bId);
                            //PostFcmData(bId,FirebaseInstanceIDService.refreshedToken,"ScoreData");
                        }
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i<beaconList.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("Beacon List "+i,beaconList.get(i));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            })
    );
}

final MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
    RequirementsWizardFactory
            .createEstimoteRequirementsWizard()
            .fulfillRequirements(this,
                    new Function0<Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke() {
                            Log.d("app", "requirements fulfilled");
                            application.enableBeaconNotifications();
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    new Function1<List<? extends Requirement>, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(List<? extends Requirement> requirements) {
                            Log.e("app", "requirements missing: " + requirements);
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    new Function1<Throwable, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.e("app", "requirements error: " + throwable);
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
```

- I saw the blog that lambda is only applied to single method. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to just move your anonymous `DisposableObserver` subclass to a named one?

Comment: But except for the above code, there are many DisposableObserver that perform different actions in my code

Comment: Using lambdas makes your code less verbose, not less messy.  Consider not logging every other line of code ...

Comment: Oh.. Thank you I understand it. I will delete the logging code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda expressions are added in Java 8. To use lambda expresssions you need to do the following inside your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Once the above changes are added, just visit the code which you want to convert to lambda. You can see a yellow bulb appearing. Just click on that and you would get an option which says "Replace with lambda".

[image]

Click on it and you can see the lambda expression now.

[image]

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#configuration

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: I couldn't see the sentence "Replace with lambda" yesterday but I reboot the AndroidStudio it worked! 
Thank you for reply!!